# IPython Notebook Magic Functions with environment variables

Tags: python, ipython, ipython-magic

Can I use an environment variable with a magicfunction such as [writefile in my ipthon notebook](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/magics.html)?

```
%env WORKING_DIR=/my/path/to/my/file
!echo $WORKING_DIR
```

> /my/path/to/my/file

but

```
%%writefile $WORKING_DIR/myfile.txt
sometext
```

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '$WORKING_DIR/myfile.txt'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%%writefile $WORKING_DIR/myfile.txt` does expansion of **Python** variable. so you need to have a `WORKING_DIR` python variable for this to work. `$FOO` works as env variable only if you are using a magics that shells out, and that get a raw `$WORKING_DIR` string. In which case the **shell** does the variable expansion.

It is possible but convoluted to do what you want, se example below:

```
In [1]: foo = 'a.py'

In [2]: %%writefile $foo
   ...: hi
   ...:
Writing a.py

In [3]: %env BAR=b.py
env: BAR=b.py

In [4]: import os

In [5]: %%writefile {os.environ['BAR']}
   ...: this is bar
   ...:
Writing b.py
```

Comment: That's what I thought, but couldn't figure out the "{}" wrap. Thank you

Comment: {smth} and $smth are the same except $smth only work on smth in `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` IIRC